# Greedy algorithm to finish a task with time constraint

Tags: analysis, greedy

This is a question from my midterm today and I wonder how to solve this. All i know is to prove the greedy algorithm using induction.

Question:

You are working on a programming project. There are n Java classes C1, C2, ..., Cn (the bossy architect says so). The architect also says that these classes have to be implemented in order (you are not allowed to implement C2 before you have completed C1 and so on).

Each of the Java classes takes at most 8 hours to implement. You work exactly 8 hours a day, and you should not leave a Java class unfinished at the end of the day.

To complete the project as soon as possible, a strategy is to implement as many classes as you can everyday. **Prove that this greedy strategy is indeed the optimal one.** 
(Hint: let ti be the total number of classes completed in the first i days using the above strategy. The strategy always stays ahead if ti is no less than the total number of classes completed in the first i days using any other strategy)

Comment: Sounds like the restrictions only give you one possible strategy - do the classes in order, starting one only if there is enough time left in the day to finish it. Any other strategy would break the rules as you've described.

Comment: @Chris but how do you prove that?

Comment: @Chris The algorithm of doing the class with the maximum time required untill you can't do any does not break any rules and is probably better.

Comment: @pperry - "The architect also says that these classes have to be implemented in order (you are not allowed to implement C2 before you have completed C1 and so on)." That sounds like a strict ordering to me.

Comment: @Chris Oh, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is incomplete. There is no indication that any class will take less than 8 hours. Since you can't leave any class unfinished, then you must start each class at the start of the day to be sure to have at least 8 hours to work on it. So if C2 really takes 3 hours and C3 really takes 5 hours, then a greedy algorithm would allow both classes to be done the same day. But after C2 takes 3 hours, you have to wait to day 3 to start C3 to be sure that you have enough time to finish since you don't know how long C3 will take.

So the restrictions really end up dictating that the effort will take *n* days, 1 day per class. So the implementation algorithm is strictly sequential, not greedy.

---

Edit **Restrictions stated in problem.**

(1) There are n Java classes C1, C2, ..., Cn

(2) these classes have to be implemented in order (you are not allowed to implement C2 before you have completed C1 and so on).

(3) Each of the Java classes takes at most 8 hours to implement

> *But there is no estimate for any class taking less than 8 hours.*

(4) You work exactly 8 hours a day

(5) You should not leave a Java class unfinished at the end of the day.

The gist of this (3,4,& 5) is let's assume that I work on class 1 for 5 minutes. I now have 7 hours 55 minutes left. Can I start on Class 2? No because it might take up to 8 hours and I must finish before the end of my 8-hour day. So I must wait to day 2 to start class 2 and so on.  Thus the implementation is strictly sequential and will take n days to complete, 1 day per class.

**In order to use the Greedy algorithm you'd need additional information.**

> (6) You also know that each class has a known number of hours needed to code the class - h1, h2, h3, ..., hn. So class 1 takes h1 hours, class 2 takes h2 hours and so on. (From item 3 no class takes more than 8 hours)

Comment: It says "each java classes take at most 8 hours". At most 8 hours so each class is for sure less than 8 hours.

Comment: You miss the point. Look at my example. You've done c2 in 3 hours. Can you start C3 with 5 hours left? All you know is (1) You must finish C3 on same day that you start and (2) C3 will take at most 8 hours. So to be sure to finish you have to wait to day 3.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the classic task scheduling case where the waiting time in the system must be minimized.

Let C1, C2, ..., C*n* your projected classes and *c*[1], *c*[2], ..., *c*[n] their required implementation time. Let's suppose you implement C1, C2, ... C*n* in this order. Therefore, the total time (waiting + implementation) for each class C*k* will be:

*c*[1] + *c*[2] + ... + *c*[*k*]

Therefore, we have the total time:

*T* = *n*·*c*[1] + (*n* – 1)·*c*[2] + ... + 2*c*[*n* – 1] + *c*[*n*] = sum(*k* = 1 to *n*) of (*n* – *k* + 1)·*c*[*k*]

(Sorry about the presentation — superscripts, subscripts, and math equations aren't supported...)

Let's suppose the implementation times in our permutation are not sorted by ascending order. We can therefore find two integers a and b such that *a* < *b* with *c*[*a*] > *c*[*b*]. If we switch them in the computation of *T*, we have:

*T'* = (*n* – *a* + 1)·*c*[*b*] + (*n* – *b* + 1)·*c*[*a*] + sum(*k* = 1 to *n* except *a*, *b*) of (*n* – *k* + 1)·*c*[*k*]

We finally compute *T* – *T'*:

*T* – *T'* = (*n* – *a* + 1)(*c*[*a*] – *c*[*b*]) + (*n* – *b* + 1)(*c*[*b*] – *c*[*a*]) = (*b* – *a*)(*c*[*a*] – *c*[*b*])

Following our initial hypothesis (*a* < *b* and *c*[*a*] > *c*[*b*]), we have *b* – *a* > 0 and *c*[*a*] – *c*[*b*] > 0 as well, hence *T* – *T'* > 0.

This proves that we decrease the total waiting time by switching any pair of tasks so that the shorter one is done first.

Your problem statement is the same, except that before starting implementing a new class, you have to check whether you should start it now (if there is enough time left on the present day) or tomorrow. But the principle proven here holds when it comes to minimizing the total "waiting" time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question for SO. The problem is not asking for a coding solution, rather its a proof that greedy is optimal. Which can be done with a proof by contradiction (no doubt taught in the class before the midterm).

What you want to do is to calculate the total time taken by greedy (there's only one solution) and disprove that any swaps in day would lead to a better solution. You probably also have to add something that mentions how swapping will allow u to permute the order to the optimal solution, if it exists.

I was going to write some formulae, but i realize Jeff Morin already has the equations, just going in the opposite direction. I think starting from the greedy solution might be easier to explain, since 'in order' is pretty much defined by the problem and you can only shift the work +- which day its done on.